# show that $(i+k)! > i!k!$ algebraically

Tags: combinatorics

I apologize in advance for asking such elementary question but I would like to show that 
$$(i+k)! > i!k!$$
I believe induction can prove it but is there an algebraic proof on proving about it?

Comment: The ratio is an integer, in Pascal's triangle

Comment: Hi, I am not familiar with combinatorics so Pascal's triangle doesn't ring a bell but I'll look it up. Thank you!

Comment: You should specify that $i$ and $k$ are positive integers since the statement is false when at least one of the variables is equal to zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Rewrite
$$(i+k)!=i!\, (i+1)\dotsm(i+k)$$
and observe each $i+j$, for $1\le j\le k$, is $>j$, so
$$\prod_{j=1}^k(i+j)>\prod_{j=1}^k j=k!$$

*Added*, on a suggestion of N. F. Taussig:

We have a strict inequality only if both $i$ and $k$ are non-zero.

Comment: ah yes! Thank you!

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the statement is false if at least one of the variables is equal to zero.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: You're right.'Tis done.